# IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition and Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, intellij-idea

Good day, i'm trying to create new project in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.1.3. I'm going to `New --> Project --> Static Web`, and i dont see twitter bootstap template in there, i have looked all over the internet how to add it there, and added a bunch of plugins, but it is still not there, can any one help please.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It seems, this feature is only available in the Ultimate Edition. It isn't mentioned specifically in the [comparison chart](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), but one can guess, since all major frameworks and even advanced HTML and CSS editing are only available in Ultimate.

Comment: @RafaelGilman, that being said; it is, of course, very easy to implement bootstrap into any site